# Is this Question still off topic?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

[When should graduates start applying for jobs?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/31361/16)

I know its an older question but it was linked to another question as a possible duplicate, as I looked at it, it seems to me that the question was both answerable and on topic.  The question is not asking about a specific job just the timing of applying for a job when graduation is imminent.  Seeing as thousands of people graduate every year this seems like a pretty good question to me.

Comment: I agree, voted to reopen.

Comment: agree, also VTRO

Comment: It's been reopened and I've gone ahead and edited the title so it's a bit more general. Tags look good.